# Transforming a JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, kendo-chart

I have the following two JavaScript arrays:

```
var grades = [ { name: "A", color: "#00FF00" }, 
               { name: "B", color: "#88CC00" },
               { name: "C", color: "#AAAA00" }, 
               { name: "D", color: "#CC8800" }, 
               { name: "F", color: "#FF0000" }];

var studentGrades = [ { Student: "James", Class: "Math", Grade: "A" },
                      { Student: "Lily", Class: "Math", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "Bob", Class: "Math", Grade: "C" },
                      { Student: "Tom", Class: "Math", Grade: "C" },
                      { Student: "James", Class: "Science", Grade: "A" },
                      { Student: "Lily", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "Bob", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "Tom", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "James", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "F" },
                      { Student: "Lily", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "A" },
                      { Student: "Bob", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "Tom", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "A" } ];
```

And I am trying to generate the following two arrays from it:

```
grades = [ { name: "A", color: "#00FF00", data: [1, 1, 2] },
                    { name: "B", color: "#88CC00", data: [1, 3, 1] },
                    { name: "C", color: "#AAAA00", data: [2, 0, 0] },
                    { name: "D", color: "#CC8800", data: [0, 0, 0] },
                    { name: "F", color: "#FF0000", data: [0, 0, 1] } ];

var classes = [ "Math", "Science", "Chemistry" ];
```

Is there an easy way to do that without looping over studentGrades and maintaining counts and a unique list of classes?

**Edit:** I created the following code after posting the question. I would still prefer an easier way to do this that is a bit more readable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/local-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example">
      <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div id="chart"></div>
      </div>
      <script>

        // Start of code that is specific to the stackoverflow question

        var grades = [ { name: "A", color: "#00FF00" }, 
                       { name: "B", color: "#88CC00" },
                       { name: "C", color: "#AAAA00" }, 
                       { name: "D", color: "#CC8800" }, 
                       { name: "F", color: "#FF0000" }];

        var studentGrades = [ { Student: "James", Class: "Math", Grade: "A" },
                              { Student: "Lily", Class: "Math", Grade: "B" },
                              { Student: "Bob", Class: "Math", Grade: "C" },
                              { Student: "Tom", Class: "Math", Grade: "C" },
                              { Student: "James", Class: "Science", Grade: "A" },
                              { Student: "Lily", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                              { Student: "Bob", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                              { Student: "Tom", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                              { Student: "James", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "F" },
                              { Student: "Lily", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "A" },
                              { Student: "Bob", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "B" },
                              { Student: "Tom", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "A" } ];

        var classes = [];

        // Returns an array that maintains the grade counts for each class based on the grades array.
        var getGradeCounts = function (studentData, gradeCounts) {
            if (gradeCounts == null) {
                gradeCounts = [];
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                if (gradeCounts[i] == undefined) {
                    gradeCounts[i] = 0;
                }
                if (grades[i].name === studentData.Grade) {
                    gradeCounts[i]++;
                }
            }
            return gradeCounts;
        }

        // Iterates over each student grade and maintains an object of the grade counts by class, and an unique array of classes used for the chart category.
        var classGradeCounts = {};
        for (var student in studentGrades) {
            var studentClass = studentGrades[student].Class;
            if (classGradeCounts[studentClass] == undefined) {
                classes.push(studentClass);
            }
            classGradeCounts[studentClass] = getGradeCounts(studentGrades[student], classGradeCounts[studentClass]);
        }

        // Now that we have the grade counts for each class, build up the chart series
        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            grades[i].data = [];
            for (var classGradeCount in classGradeCounts) {
                grades[i].data.push(classGradeCounts[classGradeCount][i]);
            }
        }

        // End of stackoverflow code, the rest of this is code is used to generate a Kendo chart.

        var chartSettings = {
            seriesDefaults: { type: "column", stack: true },
            series: grades,
            categoryAxis: { categories: classes },
        };

        function createChart() {
          $("#chart").kendoChart(chartSettings);
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
      </script>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define *easy*... Looping is inevitable, one way or the other...

Comment: Can you explain where the "data" property comes from in your chart series? You are going to have to loop over your arrays, no way around that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort and merge JSON keys with matching values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977121/sort-and-merge-json-keys-with-matching-values)

Comment: Where are you getting the data in the first snippet? You can make this problem much easier by changing the way you store this data.

Comment: @bhspencer data is an array with the count of that grade for each class. I can probably come up with a way to do this with loops and maintaining counts but was hoping there may be an easier way to do this, possibly using underscore.js or jQuery.

Comment: @bhspencer `data` is how many times a grade was given for a specific class. The index into the data array is the same index in the `classes` array. That is, `{ name: "A", color: "#00FF00", data: [1, 1, 2] }` means that there was one A for Math, one A for Science and two As for Chemistry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot avoid loops. You can give it the appearance of no loops by using functions like [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

I believe the easiest way is to create maps that give you quick access to the data you need, so you don't have to constantly scan arrays and don't need helpers like `underscore` or `jQuery`. A benefit of these maps is that you can easily use them to generate data in a different format much more easily.

You can study the following which produces the desired output and decide for yourself if it's easier than using regular loops.

```js
var grades = [ { name: "A", color: "#00FF00" }, 
               { name: "B", color: "#88CC00" },
               { name: "C", color: "#AAAA00" }, 
               { name: "D", color: "#CC8800" }, 
               { name: "F", color: "#FF0000" }];

var studentGrades = [ { Student: "James", Class: "Math", Grade: "A" },
                      { Student: "Lily", Class: "Math", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "Bob", Class: "Math", Grade: "C" },
                      { Student: "Tom", Class: "Math", Grade: "C" },
                      { Student: "James", Class: "Science", Grade: "A" },
                      { Student: "Lily", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "Bob", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "Tom", Class: "Science", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "James", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "F" },
                      { Student: "Lily", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "A" },
                      { Student: "Bob", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "B" },
                      { Student: "Tom", Class: "Chemistry", Grade: "A" } ];

var gradeMap={}, gradesByClass={}, classMap={}, classArray=[], classIndex=0;

grades.forEach(function(grade) {
    gradeMap[grade.name] = grade.color;
});
 
studentGrades.forEach(function(studentGrade){
    if (!gradesByClass[studentGrade.Class]) {
        gradesByClass[studentGrade.Class] = {};
        classMap[studentGrade.Class] = classIndex;
        classIndex++;
    }
    if(!gradesByClass[studentGrade.Class][studentGrade.Grade]) {
        gradesByClass[studentGrade.Class][studentGrade.Grade] = 0;
    }
    gradesByClass[studentGrade.Class][studentGrade.Grade]++;
});

Object.keys(classMap).forEach(function(className){
  classArray[classMap[className]] = className;
});

var finalGrades = Object.keys(gradeMap).map(function(grade){
    var obj = {
      name: grade, color: gradeMap[grade], data: []
    };
    classArray.forEach(function(className, index){
        if (gradesByClass[className] && gradesByClass[className][grade]) {
            obj.data[index] = gradesByClass[className][grade];
        } else {
            obj.data[index] = 0;
        }        
    }); 
  return obj;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalGrades));
/*
[{"name":"A","color":"#00FF00","data":[1,1,2]},
 {"name":"B","color":"#88CC00","data":[1,3,1]},
 {"name":"C","color":"#AAAA00","data":[2,0,0]},
 {"name":"D","color":"#CC8800","data":[0,0,0]},
 {"name":"F","color":"#FF0000","data":[0,0,1]}]
*/
```