# Removing duplicate Date value from a JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, morris.js

I am working on morris line chart. The json string I am getting from the service is:

```
{"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 23},
{"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 10, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-22", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-23", "A": 30, "B": 0, "C": 67},
{"SDate": "2017-01-24", "A": 0, "B": 13, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 70, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 3, "B": 45, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-26", "A": 50, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-27", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-28", "A": 80, "B": 0, "C": 0}
```

As you can see, the first top 2 rows have the same date with different values.
I want to merge the two row as one like

```
{"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 10, "B": 0, "C": 23},
```

Similarly, `2017-01-25` has 2 rows,

```
{"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 70, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 3, "B": 45, "C": 0},
```

Which I want to merge like

```
{"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 73, "B": 45, "C": 0},
```

So the final JSON string will be like

```
    {"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 10, "B": 0, "C": 23},
    {"SDate": "2017-01-22", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0},
    {"SDate": "2017-01-23", "A": 30, "B": 0, "C": 67},
    {"SDate": "2017-01-24", "A": 0, "B": 13, "C": 0},
    {"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 73, "B": 45, "C": 0},
    {"SDate": "2017-01-26", "A": 50, "B": 0, "C": 0},
    {"SDate": "2017-01-27", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0},
    {"SDate": "2017-01-28", "A": 80, "B": 0, "C": 0}
```

I know that ideally it should be handled in the backend, but I don't have any control over that and this needs to be fixed using javascript.
Right now I am trying the solution from [Sort and merge JSON keys with matching values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977121/sort-and-merge-json-keys-with-matching-values) , but not getting the desired result. 
Kindly help

**Edit 1:** 
Here A, B and C are not fixed.
This can be different sets at all.
Like X, Y or Just W or anything .
eg

```
{"SDate": "2017-01-21", "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Z": 23},....,{"SDate": "2017-01-28", "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Z": 23}
```

Or

```
{"SDate": "2017-01-21", "W": 0, "B": 0, "V": 23},......,{"SDate": "2017-01-28", "W": 0, "B": 0, "V": 23},
```

and ....
*The sets will be same for a specific string, but not necessarily A,B and C always

Comment: So, what if multiple rows have a value for `"A"`?

Comment: Is this really the full string you're getting from response? Doesn't it have containing element?

Comment: @ Cerbrus  It will add all the value, like in my 2nd case
@palasjir Yes this is the string that I am getting

Comment: @MahatmaAladdin, it is working for you ?

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai Yes. Thanks a lot. I am testing with different scenarios. will accept your answer after that.

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai  I have updated my question. Your solution is perfect if I am getting A,B and C
but it can be different as well.

Comment: @MahatmaAladdin, have a look to my answer updated.

Comment: @MahatmaAladdin, now it's working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach` method by passing a **callback** function to every item from the array.

The solution is to use a `hash` structure in order to retain only **unique** values and find out the sum of duplicate rows.

```js
let array=[{"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 23}, {"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 10, "B": 0, "C": 0}, {"SDate": "2017-01-22", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0}, {"SDate": "2017-01-23", "A": 30, "B": 0, "C": 67}, {"SDate": "2017-01-24", "A": 0, "B": 13, "C": 0}, {"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 70, "B": 0, "C": 0}, {"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 3, "B": 45, "C": 0}, {"SDate": "2017-01-26", "A": 50, "B": 0, "C": 0}, {"SDate": "2017-01-27", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0}, {"SDate": "2017-01-28", "A": 80, "B": 0, "C": 0}]
let result=[];
array.forEach(function (item) {
    if (!this[item.SDate]) {
        this[item.SDate] = { SDate: item.SDate };
        Object.keys(item).slice(1).forEach(function(key){
          this[item.SDate][key]=0;
        });
        result.push(this[item.SDate]);
    }
    Object.keys(item).slice(1).forEach(function(key){
          this[item.SDate][key]+=item[key];
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. Working fine now.
Just out of curiosity, I was working out with your code for 2 sets of arrays but it breaks in between there. Can you check this out 
https://jsfiddle.net/nishantaujju/Lwwz4fga/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

```js
let arr = [
{"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 23},
{"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 10, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-22", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-23", "A": 30, "B": 0, "C": 67},
{"SDate": "2017-01-24", "A": 0, "B": 13, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 70, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 3, "B": 45, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-26", "A": 50, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-27", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0},
{"SDate": "2017-01-28", "A": 80, "B": 0, "C": 0}
];

arr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
        if(a.SDate < b.SDate)
            return -1;
        if(a.SDate > b.SDate)
            return 1;
        return 0;
}).reduce((a, b) => {
    if(a.length == 0){
        a.push(b);
    }
    else if(a[a.length-1].SDate != b.SDate){
        a.push(b);
    }
    else {
        a[a.length-1].A += b.A;
        a[a.length-1].B += b.B;
        a[a.length-1].C += b.C;
    }
    return a;
}, [])

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Try it with twice the amount of entries in the array.

Comment: Yea, that looks better!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a different approach...

```
var yourData = [
  {"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 23},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-21", "A": 10, "B": 0, "C": 0},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-22", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-23", "A": 30, "B": 0, "C": 67},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-24", "A": 0, "B": 13, "C": 0},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 70, "B": 0, "C": 0},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-25", "A": 3, "B": 45, "C": 0},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-26", "A": 50, "B": 0, "C": 0},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-27", "A": 20, "B": 0, "C": 0},
  {"SDate": "2017-01-28", "A": 80, "B": 0, "C": 0}
];

var newData = {};

// Create an object using dates as indexes, so we can find it on each loop.
$.each(yourData,function(id,value) {

    if (!newData[value['SDate']])
        newData[value['SDate']] = {"SDate": value.SDate, "A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0};

    newData[value['SDate']]["A"] += value.A;
    newData[value['SDate']]["B"] += value.B;
    newData[value['SDate']]["C"] += value.C;
});

// Remove indexes and get the desired array of values.
newData = $.map(newData,function(value,index) {
  return value;
});

console.log(newData);
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dynamic approach with a hash table and a variable for the key, you like to group on.

The rest of all properties are taken for summing.

```js
var data = [{ SDate: "2017-01-21", A: 0, B: 0, C: 23 }, { SDate: "2017-01-21", A: 10, B: 0, C: 0 }, { SDate: "2017-01-22", A: 20, B: 0, C: 0 }, { SDate: "2017-01-23", A: 30, B: 0, C: 67 }, { SDate: "2017-01-24", A: 0, B: 13, C: 0 }, { SDate: "2017-01-25", A: 70, B: 0, C: 0 }, { SDate: "2017-01-25", A: 3, B: 45, C: 0 }, { SDate: "2017-01-26", A: 50, B: 0, C: 0 }, { SDate: "2017-01-27", A: 20, B: 0, C: 0 }, { SDate: "2017-01-28", A: 80, B: 0, C: 0 }],
    groupBy = 'SDate',
    hash = Object.create(null),
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!hash[o[groupBy]]) {
        hash[o[groupBy]] = {};
        hash[o[groupBy]][groupBy] = o[groupBy];
        grouped.push(hash[o[groupBy]]);
    }
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k === groupBy) {
            return;
        }
        hash[o[groupBy]][k] = (hash[o[groupBy]][k] || 0) + o[k];
    });
});
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```